# WinRT HttpClient, POST request

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to send the POST request below in a WinRT App.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I18Bh.png]

This is the code i use:

```
var pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
  new KeyValuePair<string, string>("MinOraPart", "01:00"),
  new KeyValuePair<string, string>("MaxOraPart", "23:59"),
  new KeyValuePair<string, string>("TIPOVIS", "FERMATE"),
  new KeyValuePair<string, string>("CAMBIOCOMUNE", "0"),
  new KeyValuePair<string, string>("DescLocPart", "PADOVA AUTOSTAZIONE"),
  new KeyValuePair<string, string>("DescLocDest", "ROVIGO AUTOSTAZIONE"),
  new KeyValuePair<string, string>("direzione", "ANDATA"),
  new KeyValuePair<string, string>("gg", ""),
  new KeyValuePair<string, string>("meseanno", ""),
  new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ControlloEsisteFermata", "0"),
  new KeyValuePair<string, string>("PARTENZA", ""),
  new KeyValuePair<string, string>("LocPartenza", "348|PADOVA AUTOSTAZIONE|0"),
  new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ARRIVO", ""),
  new KeyValuePair<string, string>("LocArrivo", "453|ROVIGO AUTOSTAZIONE|0"),
  new KeyValuePair<string, string>("dataViaggio", "14/11/2013"),
  new KeyValuePair<string, string>("OREDalSol", "01:00"),
  new KeyValuePair<string, string>("OREAlSol", "23:59"),
  new KeyValuePair<string, string>("fascia", "libera"),
  new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ordine", "NumCambi, OraPart"),
  new KeyValuePair<string, string>("MaxNodi", "1"),
  new KeyValuePair<string, string>("MinimoV", "0"),
  new KeyValuePair<string, string>("CERCA_ANDATA", "corse di ANDATA")
}
var content = new StringContent(pairs);
content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.PostAsync("http://ro.autobus.it/ro/asp/RicercaOrari.asp?User=SITA", content);
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    //Extract the data from the webpage
}
```

It works since i get the HTML code from the server, but the page i recive doesn't contain the query result, it's just the search page without the results.

It seems that miss something in the request, any suggestion?

Comment: do you have a working query to compare it to? At a quick glance, it looks OK ...

Comment: the query in the screenshot works, i don't have the source code of the page.
This is the full postdata string:
`MinOraPart=16%3A30&MaxOraPart=23%3A59&TIPOVIS=FERMATE&CAMBIOCOMUNE=0&DesLocPart=PADOVA+AUTOSTAZIONE&DesLocDest=ROVIGO+AUTOSTAZIONE&direzione=ANDATA&gg=&meseanno=&controlloEsisteFermata=0&PARTENZA=PADOVA+AUTOSTAZIONE&LocPart=348%7CPADOVA+AUTOSTAZIONE%7C0&ARRIVO=ROVIGO+AUTOSTAZIONE&LocDest=453%7CROVIGO+AUTOSTAZIONE%7C0&dataViaggio=20%2F11%2F2013&OREDalSel=16%3A30&OREAlSel=23%3A59&fascia=libera&ordine=NumCambi%2C+OraPart&MaxNodi=2&MinimoV=0&CERCA_ANDATA=corse+di+ANDATA`

Comment: See if you can use Fiddler to capture working/non-working. It might be a cookie, a HTTP header, etc. It's really hard to debug this type of issue when you don't have the server's source available.

Comment: There is a cookie for an ASP session that i recive the first time i visit the page (via browser).

Comment: Are you sending it in your code? You should make the same exact request and then eliminate extra stuff if you want to simplify your app.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to convert that array of pairs into a [percent-encoded string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). Unfortunately, there is no `NameValueCollection` class in WinRT. But it is not too hard to make an equivalent function. E.g.:

```
private string ToPercentEncoding(List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> pairs)
{
    List<string> joinedPairs = new List<string>();
    foreach (var pair in pairs)
    {
        joinedPairs.Add(
            System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(pair.Key) +
            "=" +
            System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(pair.Value));
    }

    return String.Join("&", joinedPairs);
}
```

Then, just call the function from your code and pass the result to the `StringContent` class:

```
private async void Foo(){
    var pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("MinOraPart", "01:00"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("MaxOraPart", "23:59"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("TIPOVIS", "FERMATE"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("CAMBIOCOMUNE", "0"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("DescLocPart", "PADOVA AUTOSTAZIONE"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("DescLocDest", "ROVIGO AUTOSTAZIONE"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("direzione", "ANDATA"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("gg", ""),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("meseanno", ""),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ControlloEsisteFermata", "0"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("PARTENZA", ""),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("LocPartenza", "348|PADOVA AUTOSTAZIONE|0"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ARRIVO", ""),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("LocArrivo", "453|ROVIGO AUTOSTAZIONE|0"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("dataViaggio", "14/11/2013"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("OREDalSol", "01:00"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("OREAlSol", "23:59"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("fascia", "libera"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ordine", "NumCambi, OraPart"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("MaxNodi", "1"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("MinimoV", "0"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("CERCA_ANDATA", "corse di ANDATA")
    };

    var content = new StringContent(ToPercentEncoding(pairs));
    content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost", content);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        //Extract the data from the webpage.
    }
}
```

And that's all, the rest of your code works as expected.

**UPDATE:**

Some of your keys are wrong, it is *DesLocDest* and not *DescLocDest*.

You will definitely need to set the cookie, at least the one starting with *ASPSESSIONId...*.

If that's not enough, try setting the *User-Agent* and *Origin* headers.

Comment: Still not working... 
I even tried with
`var content = new StringContent(postDataString));`
where postDataString is the encoded string that i get from Tamper Data (an AddOn for Firefox that shows GET/POST request)

Comment: What exactly is not working? Can you share Fiddler traces of the request and the response?

Comment: Still not enough, fixed-up the keys, added the session cookie and the User-Agent/Origin headers.

Now the request is:
`POST /ro/asp/RicercaOrari.asp?User=SITA HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/plain
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
Referer: http://ro.autobus.it/ro/asp/RicercaOrari.asp?User=SITA
Origin: http://ro.autobus.it
Accept-Language: it-IT; q=0.8
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: ro.autobus.it
Cookie: ASPSESSIONIDCQBCDBAD=BIIMCHCCMJMGHELMAMPAGOOF
Content-Length: 470
Expect: 100-continue`